# Load image from network shared folder using quasar and vue 3

Tags: vue.js, image-processing, vuejs3, quasar

Good Day everyone!

I am new in web development, I have a database which contains image file paths located in a network shared folder that I want to load in a quasar project.

example of the data: \192.168.8.198\pics\sample.jpg

I tried loading it directly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzH7q.png)

and this is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fefwz.png)

can anyone please help...

Comment: It means what it says, you can't do that. You need web server to serve static files. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I see.. Thank you very much @EstusFlask